# how to check out svn file from server file:///abc/def from outside environment

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I have a server where the folder is stored.
When I type

```
svn info
```

on the server, it says:

```
URL: file:///abc/def
```

If I want to checkout a copy into a local machine from the server, 
how can I find the corresponding http address?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- You **must** to have any ([svnserve](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html)|[httpd](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic)) server, which will provide remote access to repo
- In case of such server, you have to find server's config (or starting script), where you'll find all configuration setting

In common case - you can't predict (more true for http://, less for svn://) URL of repository with local path only

Comment: Normally where are those config files? I tried ~/.subversion/ but couldn't find any information there.

Comment: @cxf54 - ~/.subversion/ is config-path for Subversion **clients**, server part *may be* inside Apache's httpd.conf or in starting svnserve line. Check with ps -xa, does you have *any* server running

Comment: I solved the problem by using svn co svn+ssh http://abc/svn_location. Thanks, Lazy